# How to solve a problem in a form, it keeps thinking after the user hits the submit button

Tags: wordpress, elementor

**Hello, good day.**
Let's see if you can help me or guide me.
I have a problem with a form that I have in my wordpress, it is built in elementor, but when I click on submit on the form

1- keeps thinking
2- I have to redirect to a thank you page and it doesn't
3- If I receive the email with the lead, but the user is left with the idea that it is not sent because they are thinking about the button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OifeQ.png)

I already checked that it did not have a strange element like # in the labels

Comment: This must be an issue with the form. But since nobody can check your form or the html or the javascript involved, it is up to you to solve this.

Comment: I already solved it, I needed a configuration in the mail with an SMTP protocol.

Everything is working now!

Thank you.